# How to send multiple in memory workbooks in HttpResponse

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have been faced with a problem at hand. I have to create an export functionality for our in house time management system. There is an export button and if we click on that all the data gets exported to an excel sheet.

The use case is that if the data to be exported contains data for multiple years then separate workbooks needs to be created one for each year.

I have been able to create multiple workbooks but I am finding it difficult to send those created in-memory workbooks back in a HttpResponse object.

I have tried using ZipOutputStream solution as well but turns out that we can only add physical files in ZipEntry objects.

Any type of help is appreciated.

Comment: Create one workbook, and use one sheet per year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried using ZipOutputStream solution as well but turns out that
>   we can only add physical files in ZipEntry objects.

Not true:

```
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(...);
byte[] workBook; //Assign from your POI output
zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("export-for-2016.xls"));
zos.write(workBook);
zos.closeEntry();
```

(**UPDATE** for clarity) The last three method calls there can be used as many times as you need to add objects to the zip file.

Apache commons-compress is generally better, but that should get you started.

Comment: But this will again let me send one workbook only. I need to send multiple workbooks in one ZipOutputStream

Comment: And again, that's not true. There is absolutely no reason you can't call the methods I showed above multiple times to write a dozen files to a single ZipOutputStream. I've done this sort of thing for a customer, only with PDF files. It's perfectly doable unless your goal is trick the HTTP response into sending multiple independent file attachments which would be a violation of the HTTP spec.

Comment: I agree to what you say. I have tried it out now and its working, Thanks for a detailed answer.